# SXA pdf files search issue

Tags: content-search, sxa, computed-field

In our Sitecore SXA solution, searching for pdf files is failing.
In our case, the files are stored under a separate media folder which is under the actual site node.
We have installed the pdf IFilter as per steps in this link but still no luck.
https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/5/t/1834

Any clue as to why its failing?

Also, have seen this computed field "sxacontent" for sxa search.
What does this field actually contain? What fields are included in this computed field?

Comment: `sxacontent` is a computed field which includes fields on items that are not excluded and,I believe, inherited from `_Searchable` template. The index may list the fields that are included. You'll also see content from data sourced items that are associated by components on the page.